# Minimize php processes

Tags: php, jquery

I've got a page that makes a lot of jQuery ajax requests periodically, asking for a response from  a php function as such:

```
$.ajax({
      url: "functions.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: {action : 'getData', id : draftid},
      dataType: "html"
    }).done(function(output) {
        $("#myDiv").html(output);
    });
```

Now when I look at the running tasks on my machine while I have this one page open, I'll see four or five php tasks running. I'm planning on having this page running simultaneously across multiple pages, and I've got the feeling my host won't be too happy about that.

Is there another method I can use to get jQuery the information I'm getting from the php scripts (mainly MySQL requests) to minimize the task quantity and CPU usage?

EDIT: The functions.php file is basically just a switch statement that calls the requested function which makes a SQL request and returns the relevant data.

I do not know the specifics on what the PHP tasks are. When I run top, I see many processes with the command 'php'. I'm no Linux pro, so perhaps there's a command I can run to figure out what these processes are doing more specifically?

Comment: If you are polling for changed data, not submitting data, you can try comet. But that'll just swap many short processes with fewer long ones.

Comment: Impossible to tell without seeing any of your PHP code. Besides, what are the four processes? Are they taxing? Are they persistent? Are you caching data where applicable to reduce stress on MySQL? These are all things to consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you combine any of the requests together into one request? you'll have to parse the return data somehow, but that's not a big deal. Do you have control over the server? If so, you could try a web server with fast-cgi to control the number of running processes and pool db connections.

Answer (score 0):

Optimized SQL Querys, maybe build caching systems when its possible ? (Don't know what youre programming there!)

Also you can switch to another Webserver which is more performant (I would prefer Litespeed which is about 60% faster then Apache)

Also don't wonder if Apache is running multiple instances at once thats normal at apache.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more information I cant say to much but no you cant directly connect to a mysql server from javascript. Depending on what data you need there may be ways to significantly cut down on the back end processing.

Some generic ideas:

- Combine your ajaxs requests into a single "heartbeat"/update request so you only have 1 process running
- If you can do some backend caching of db data with somthing like memcache
- Profile and optimise your ajax requests using XDEBUG and webgrind